# can we automate Green Screen through Selenium or QTP?

Tags: testing, automation, selenium-webdriver, qtp

we have customer provide architecture where they have use i series DB (green screen) and we have DB testing in scope for the contract. can some one help me to get more idea on how and which tool will be best fit for automation of these controls.

Thanks in Advance.

Comment: There is terminal emulation support available for QTP. And you can use the database checkpoint, or custom code, to check database contents. See HP site for details. Or state exactly what terminal emulation you are using, and more precise tips might pour in.

Comment: On the Selenium front - Unless there is a web front end to the DB (like http://www.bcdsoftware.com/iseries400solutions/presto/), Selenium will be no good. This is not clear from your question

Answer (score -1):

I suggest you to explore the possibilities of the java jdbc architecture to access and retrieve values from the database. You can use the the retrieved values to validate. :)

```
import java.sql.Connection;
import java.sql.DriverManager;
import java.sql.PreparedStatement;
import java.sql.ResultSet;
import java.sql.SQLException;

public class DatabaseConnections {
    private Connection connection = null;

    public Connection getDBConnectionQKB9() {
        System.out
                .println("DATABASE CONNECTION  - Oracle JDBC Connection initialization");

        try {
            Class.forName("oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver");

            connection = DriverManager.getConnection(url, user, password);

            if (connection != null) {
                System.out
                        .println("DATABASE CONNECTION - Gained control - QKB9 database");
            } else {
                System.out
                        .println("DATABASE CONNECTION - Failed to make connection - QKB9 database");
            }
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    public void getData() {
        try {
            PreparedStatement pt= connection.prepareStatement(query);
            ResultSet rs = pt.executeQuery();

            while (rs.next()) {
                //insert code to validate
            }
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }



    public void closeDBConnection() {
        try {
            connection.close();
        } catch (SQLException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: This answer doesn't address the problem